# How to get data only one time and use it in union query

Tags: sql, db2, union

My query to get person and information about his friend or parent:

```
select civils.name, friends.fullName as full_name, friends.age as age, friends.height as height 
from (query to get list people in city) as civils
inner join friends on civils.friendId = friends.Id and friends.name = "John"
union
select civils.name, parents.fullName as full_name, parents.age as age, parents.height as height 
from (query to get list people in city) as civils
inner join parents on civils.parentId = parents.Id and parents.name = "John"
```

But i don't want to waste resource for twice getting civils. How to get list data in one time and use it for two inner joins like this:

```
select civils.name, full_name, age, height from (query to get list people in city) as civils
inner join friends on civils.friendId = friends.Id and friends.name = "John"
union
inner join parents on civils.parentId = parents.Id and parents.name = "John"
```

I'm using DB2.

**Updated:**
Sorry for unclear question, I expect the result formart like this:

```
civils.name | full_name | age | height
```

But if I tried solutions like suggested answers, the result format will be:

```
civils.name | friends.full_name | friends.age | friends.height | parents.full_name | parents.age | parents.height
```

and I have to do one more step to convert this list to my expected format list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little concerned about what you may be doing in your `civils` reference, but you can wrap it as a CTE:

```
WITH Civil_List AS (<query to get list people in city>) 

SELECT Civils.name, Friends.full_name, Friends.age, Friends.height
FROM Civils_List
JOIN Friends 
  ON Friends.id  = Civils_List.friendId
     AND Friends.name = 'John' 
UNION 
SELECT Civils.name, Parents.full_name, Parents.age, Parents.height
FROM Civils_List
JOIN Parents 
  ON Parents.id  = Civils_List.friendId
     AND Parents.name = 'John'
```

Comment: If have no way to done it in one query, i will use your query. It covers all cases.

Comment: @qmn1711 - The desired result list was critical information.  We initially thought you we just looking for the _existence_ of those records, not any of the values from them (or the necessary format).

Comment: yes, i did miss this critical information. I used your query in my app, thanks!